# Can any one identify this component or tell me a way to do so?

Tags: components

Can anyone identify this component or tell me a way to do so?

Unfortunately I do not have access to a circuit diagram.

The component burnt out when I reversed polarity by mistake...

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE ----

The board is from a MEI Cashflow 330 coin validator.

Link to product www.norpay.se/pdf/cf3xx_4xx/330_dg_gb5_142799044.pdf

[image: Board Back]

[image: Board Front]

Comment: It's *was* a resistor, I would say... If you ask about it's value, I don't think it is recoverable.

Comment: Could you provide some info on what device it is, and a broader view of the circuit so we can get a better idea of what part of the circuit it belongs to.

Comment: You show two sides of a whole board.  That's good for context, but which component where are you asking about?  A closeup of the specific component would be useful too.

Comment: What are the numbers on the small IC on the front side. S7 or something?

Answer (score 1):

I'm like 80 percent sure that that part connects to what I believe is a 78L05 VIN pin. It also connects to two small input caps. Based on that and the product sheet you posted that it's either a 12v 2A fuse, or a reverse protection diode.

If the pins at the top where marked, you could check to see if it is a 12v input pin.

Answer (score 0):

Given its' size, the fact that it's connected to a fat trace, and the fact that it failed under reverse voltage, I'd vote for a tantalum or electrolytic capacitor (probably tantalum).

However, although it was good of you to provide a link to the product document, you should be aware that the PCB shown in the PDF bears no resemblance to the board you have. This makes it very difficult to tell anything about your board.

Comment: Unfortunately the board is hidden within the mechanism and I can find no other reference martial for the validator. I appreciate its a big ask and appreciate your comments. Looks like a school boy polarity error could be very costly..